# Cannot pip install adafruit-circuitpython-mlx90640

Tags: python, pip, adafruit

I am trying to install adafruit-circuitpython-mlx90640, a library for the MLX90640 thermal camera. When I run `sudo pip install adafruit-circuitpython-mlx90640` I get an error that `no matching distribution is found for Adafruit-Blinka`. So I tried to `pip install Adafruit-Blinka` and get the same error: `no matching distribution is found for Adafruit-Blinka`. Any ideas on how to get it to work?

One more thing that I have tried:
The default version on my raspberry pi is 3.4. I have installed Berryconda, which is a version of Anaconda for the RPi. In Berryconda the Python version is 3.6 and pip (not pip3) works with it. Pip3 installs Adafruit-Blinka but it goes into python 3.4. I would like it to be installed into Python 3.6. I think if I were to point Pip3 to the Berryconda version of Python, my problem would be solved (but not sure).

Comment: pip is for python 2. If you want to install it for Python 3, use pip3.

Answer (score 2):

As ben_nuttall says, you must use `pip3`. Circuitpython is Python 3 only!

`sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-mlx90640`